# undefined reference error when building TensorFlow Lite image classification with cmake

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, delegates, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to compile the TensorFlow lite code with XNNPACK delegate enabled for the [C++ image classification demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image).

I see it is possible to build it with bazel. However, I would like to know how to build it with cmake.

If I disable the XNNPACK, it works.

```
cmake -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF ../tensorflow/lite
cmake --build . -j -t label_image
```

But if I enable the XNNPACK, it gives me undefined reference error.

```
cmake -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=ON ../tensorflow/lite
cmake --build . -j -t label_image
```

The error message is shown below.

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/__/__/tools/tool_params.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable label_image
CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/__/__/tools/evaluation/utils.cc.o: In function `tflite::evaluation::CreateXNNPACKDelegate(TfLiteXNNPackDelegateOptions const*)':
utils.cc:(.text+0x9ce): undefined reference to `TfLiteXnnpackDelegatePluginCApi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/build.make:370: recipe for target 'examples/label_image/label_image' failed
make[3]: *** [examples/label_image/label_image] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6488: recipe for target 'examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6495: recipe for target 'examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/label_image/CMakeFiles/label_image.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:2262: recipe for target 'label_image' failed
make: *** [label_image] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to enable XNNPACK in TensorFlow Lite image classification with cmake?

Thank you

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. Did you find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(TFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK)
  list(APPEND TFLITE_LABEL_IMAGE_SRCS
    ${TFLITE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/delegates/xnnpack_delegate_provider.cc
  )
  list(APPEND TFLITE_LABEL_IMAGE_SRCS
    ${TFLITE_SOURCE_DIR}/core/acceleration/configuration/c/xnnpack_plugin.cc
  )
else()
  set(TFLITE_LABEL_IMAGE_CC_OPTIONS "-DTFLITE_WITHOUT_XNNPACK")
endif()  # TFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK
```

Comment: It would help if you also include text about how and where to use your code, adding supporting information makes it easier for other users to understand, utilise, and verify your answer.